# Angular and ERROR: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I don't know how to fix my problem. I have a table with rows In one of the columns there should be displayed some icon (data fetched from the backend service) but I get the following error in the console:

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: undefined'. Current value: 'ngIf: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAk

Then I added

```
     setLogoImage(logo: any) {
    if (logo) {
      this.imgURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + logo;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

And my template:

```
 <ng-template let-columns="columns" let-rowData pTemplate="body">
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-resizable-column">{{ rowData['name'] || '' }}</td>
      <td class="ui-resizable-column">{{ rowData['active'] | yesNoBoolean }}</td>
      <td class="ui-resizable-column">
       //some data
      </td>
      <td class="ui-resizable-column">{{ setLogoImage(rowData['logo']) }}<img *ngIf="imgURL"
                                                                              [src]="imgURL" height="50"
                                                                              width="50" alt="logo"></td>
      <td class...
```

Currently icons are displayed without any errors BUT in the wrong order! Everything is shifted down one row! Do you have any idea how to fix that?

**UPDATE**

Hmm it doesn't work. After changes:

```
   export class FrameworkSearchResultsComponent extends PaginationComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
    
   constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pagination.sort = 'name,ASC';
    this.setPage.subscribe(val => {
      if (this.table) {
        this.table.first = val;
      }
    });
  }
    
    
    setLogoImage(logo: any) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (logo) {
            this.imgURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + logo;
          }
        }, 100);
      }
    
      ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }
```

my icons flash very often and wrong icons are display, eg. in row 1 and 2 are displayed the same icons (but in reality are different in each row)

Comment: do you mind showing in your questions the remainders of the function above `setLogoImage(logo: any)` ? there might be an opportunity to delay the change on the  `imgURL` assignment

Answer (score 1):

Angular runs change detection on component in intervals or on events. What happened in your case is that you made change to data/view after angular ran it's change detection and before the next change detection cycle.

Hence, angular will the change you have made in between. The code will work but it's not guaranteed that it will work 100% of the time.

The line that's generating error with you is most possibly this with `imgUrl`:
`<img *ngIf="imgURL" [src]="imgURL" height="50" width="50" alt="logo">`

You need to assign the `imgUrl` in a change hook like `ngOnInit` etc or encapsulate it in a `settimeout` to delay the change for 50 to 100 milleseconds. You will then not need to run the change detection manually

```
setLogoImage(logo: any) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
     if (logo) {
      this.imgURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + logo;
    }
  },100);
}
```

Comment: Updated my code... Unfortunately doesn't work... Maybe I did something wrong

Comment: And you're right the problem is related to imgUrl... When I remove *ngIf="imgURL" from my template then icons are displayed in a good order but then icons are displayed in each row, what is not desirable

Comment: @Matley increase the timeout in from 100 to 200 and then keep incrementing till the issue is gone

Comment: What do you mean by 'and then keep incrementing till the issue is gone'?

Comment: @Matley i mean the delay in `setTimeout` i.e `setTimeout(()=>{},200)` then `setTimeout` i.e `setTimeout(()=>{},300)` then `setTimeout` i.e `setTimeout(()=>{},400)`, at a certain delay, you will not see the issue

Comment: Alternative is to assign the imgUrl variable in a proper change cycle

Comment: Your first solution with setTimeout doesn't work for me, if I set delay eg. to 500 then I have to wait a coupe of seconds till my page is fully loaded (and my loading spinner is displayed for long time)...and after loading all icons the order is still wrong... So maybe should I somehow assign the imgURL variable in some hook?

Comment: Your order depends on the order of the items in array, angular just renders the dom in that order. 500 is in milliseconds = 0.5s so it shouldn't be that much delay. It's not the solution but a hacky patch in case you aren't able to move your variable assignment within a change detection cycle

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed my problem by changing method setLogoImage to getLogoImage:

```
  getLogoImage(logo: any) {
    if (logo) {
      return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + logo;
    }
  }
```

And some small changes in template:

```
<td class="ui-resizable-column"><img *ngIf="rowData['logo']"
                                           [src]="getLogoImage(rowData['logo'])" height="50"
                                           width="50" alt="logo"></td>
```